# Anyway of making the IDs sorted?

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have `1061` users in my website and I delete ones that haven't paid every so often. I don't like how it says `ID: 304` and then skips to `ID:400`...

Is there any way of changing the system so when I delete someone it changes their `ID` to e.g. `305` and then carries on?

This is OCD and really annoying me.

Comment: why would you like do that? are there any referencing tables?

Comment: Live with it. Primary keys are never altered and they should stick that way.

Comment: tbh I will do it manually if I have to :P

Comment: I would advise against changing primary keys OCD or not. But if you do, backup your DB first.

Comment: no don't do that, it's a bad idea. keep incriminating id's count. that way you will save your self from trouble.

Comment: If your website shows the userid (either as a get variable), just make another column called myuserid, and never touch the variable (id) that you're using to reference.

Comment: Worry about making your application better for the users and not making sure there are no gaps in your ids.  Why are you deleting user records anyway?  Just deactivate them.  Your customers might want to revive their account at some point.  Or maybe you can send emails to people that haven't paid in a while to ask them to come back.  You are deleting potentially useful data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not common practice but you could execute a

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

after every removal of user

Then every new inserted user will get the first available id. I must say again this is not pretty. You must make sure that when an id is removed, anything that is based or connected somehow on that id must also be removed.

Comment: Also you better make sure you have `ON DELETE CASCADE`, if your table is being referenced, another user taking the ID of a delete user will cause issues.

Answer (score 8):

The only way to have consecutively numbered ids is to write lots and lots of code, and shutdwon access to your system regularly while it rebuilds the numbering. i.e. trying to get the result you want is very, very difficult and disruptive.

It's not broken.

Don't try to fix it.

Comment: I spose... I just changed them all by hand in the end :P

Answer (score 0):

When you delete user, you can run
`UPDATE users SET id = id - 1 WHERE id > X order by id ASC`
where `X` is the ID of the deleted user
then you have to alter the next autoincrement
`ALTER TABLE users SET AUTO_INCREMENT = Y`
where `Y` is `MAX(id) + 1`

Comment: ....and use foreign key constraints. And don't use transactions (because they might roll back) and don't ever plan on upgrading to a replication cluster (because the numbers are notallocated sequentially) or any sort of federated system. And never release ids outside your application - because people won't find their data.....